# Get field data from database to populate form fields for a user who has already submitted the form

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I built a model form wherein I want a user to first login and then fill my form fields. For a **new user with no previous submission, I want the form to be blank**. For a **customer who has submitted the form before**, I want to get the id of that **logged in customer** making GET request and retrieve field values from database to populate the form, with data he previously entered to submit the form.

At the moment I am trying this approach to get id of logged in user to populate the fields in views.py

```
cur_customer = Customer.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
```

This however gives me an error saying **Customer matching query does not exist**.

So how would I implement this?

views.py

```
def multi_form(request):
        form=RegForm()
        if request.method=='POST':
            form=RegForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                messages.success(request, "Your Response has been recorded")
                context={'form':form}
                return render(request, 'customer/index.html', context)
            else :
                return render(request, 'customer/index.html', {'form': form})

        else:
            
            cur_customer = Customer.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
            form=RegForm(initial={
                    'first_name':cur_customer.get('first_name',''),
                    'last_name':cur_customer.get('last_name','')})
            context = {'form': form}
            return render(request, 'customer/index.html', context)
```

models.py

```
class Customer(models.Model):

    id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True, default=None)
    customerReg=models.OneToOneField(CustomerReg, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    first_name=models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False, default=None)
    last_name=models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False, default=None)

class CustomerReg(models.Model):
    user=models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    email=models.EmailField(max_length=254)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `request.user.is_authenticated` in your view to check whether there is a user who is logged in. You are currently trying to retrieve a user while no one is logged in, so you should put that check into your view:

```
def multi_form(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        form=RegForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, "Your Response has been recorded")
            context={'form':form}
            return render(request, 'customer/index.html', context)
        else :
            return render(request, 'customer/index.html', {'form': form})

    else:
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            form = RegForm(initial={
                'first_name':request.user.first_name,
                'last_name':request.user.last_name})
        else:
            form = RegForm()

        context = {'form': form}
        return render(request, 'customer/index.html', context)
```

This of course assumes that your current customer and the user who is currently logged in are always the same person.

Comment: AttributeError at /form/
'User' object has no attribute 'get'
This is what I get now.

Comment: @Shaurya try using `request.user.first_name` and `request.user.last_name`

Comment: no effects on reloading the page. The fields are empty.

Comment: `if request.user.is_authenticated:
form = RegForm(initial={
                    'first_name':request.user.first_name,
                    'last_name':request.user.last_name})`
This is my altered code @voodoo-burger

Comment: @Shaurya are you sure the names of your form fields are `first_name` and `last_name`?

Comment: @Shaurya and is there someone actually logged in?

Comment: Yes first_name and last_name as specified in question above for model. The form is a model form. I am able to see data stored in my database.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220445/discussion-between-shaurya-and-voodoo-burger).

Comment: Yes there is a person logged in. request.user is printing on the webpage the username of logged in user. But user is separate model and Customer as shown above is a different model. Do you want me to link customer model with one to one field to user model instead of CustomerReg model?

Comment: `'first_name':request.user.get('first_name','')` this fills first_name field with the username of logged in person but when I use request.user.first_name it appears blank